# Existence simply connected manifold of $\dim=6$ with $H_2(M)=0$ and $\chi(M)=1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to do the following exercise :

> Show that there does not exist a simply connected closed manifold of dimension $6$ with $H_2(M)=0$ and $\chi(M)=1$.

First thing we notice is that since $M$ is simply connected then it's orientable.  Now using Poincare-Duality and the universal coefficients theorem we know that $\mathrm{rk} (H_i)= \mathrm{rk}(H_{6-i}(M))$.  From the fact that $\chi(M)=1$, and that $H_2(M)=0=H_1(M)$ we obtain that $\mathrm{rk}(H_3(M))=1$.  Now I don't know how to go from here.

Any hint is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the title you write $\chi(M) = 0$, but in the post you use $\chi(M) = 1$. Which one do you mean?

Comment: My bad , I meant $\chi(M)=1$. @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: Hint: Consider the intersection form on $H_3$. Is it symmetric or skew-symmetric?

Comment: Fredrik's method can be extended to prove that for any compact orientable manifold of dimension $4n+2$. $H_{2n+1}$ can only have even rank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have shown that $\text{rank}(H^3(M))=\text{rank}(H_3(M))=1$. Thus $H^3(M)$ module torsion is a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by a cocycle $\alpha\in H^3(M)$. Let $H^3_f(M)$ denote the subgroup of $H^3(M)$ generated by $\alpha$. The cup product pairing
$$
H^3_f(M)\times H^3_f(M) \overset{(\varphi,\psi)\mapsto(\varphi\smile \psi)[M]}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{Z}
$$
is non-singular and sends $(\alpha,\alpha)$ to a generator, and by graded commutativity of the cohomology ring of $M$, we get that this is a skew-symmetric form. Any skew-symmetric non-singular form can only exists for even-dimensional rank. This implies that $H^3_f(M)$ is even-dimensional which is a contradiction.